# Consulta en SQL Server y envío por correo en formato HTML

Tags: html, sql, sql-server

Tengo el siguiente script que envia la consulta en formato HTML vía correo electrónico:

```
declare 
@table_html nvarchar (max), 

set @table_html =
N'<html>'+
N'<head>'+
N'<style type="text/css">table{border: solid 1px;border-collapse:collapse;}td{text-align:"center";}.izq{text-align:left}th{text-align:"center";  background:"#808080"; color:"#ffffff";}</style>' +
N'</head>'+
N'<body>'+
N'<h3><center><u>REPORTE DE MONITOREO<u></center></h3>'+
N'<table border =''1'' align = "center">' +
N'<tr><th>COLUM 1</th>'+
N'<th>COLUM 2 </th>'+
N'<th>COLUM 3</th>'+
N'<th>COLUM 4</th>'+
cast (
(select  [td class = "izq"]= Colum 1, '',
         td = Colum 2, '',
         td = Colum 3, '',
         td = Colum 4, ''
from    MI_TABLA

for xml raw('tr'), elements
) as nvarchar (max)
) + n'</table>'+
N'<body>'+
N'<html>';

-- procedimiento para envío de correo:
exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'Notificaciones SQL',
@recipients = 'gerenteTI@mail.com’,
@copy_recipients ='DBA@mail.com',
@subject = 'Reporte – Servidor 1',
@body= @table_html,
@body_format = 'html';
```

El problema que tengo es de no poder darle formato solo a la etiqueta `<td>` del HTML que corresponde a la primera columna, quiero que los datos de la primera columna me salga ubicada a la izquierda. He intentado ponerle un atributo class y citarlo en la cabecera `<style>` pero por lo visto no es el camino por que no me genera la consulta.

En resumen, les muestro el formato que me llega al correo con el formato que desearía que tuviera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te da error al generar la consulta? ,no veo problema en que coloques el estilo como planteas en la pregunta. Coloca el código de cómo lo intentaste hacer a ver. Saludos.

Comment: @zerocool, he añadido este código css : `.izq{text-align:left}` en la etiqueta de estilos añadiendo antes la etiqueta `"izq"` en el primer `td`dentro de la consulta `select.` Recuerdo haberlo visto de esa manera en una página web, pero ese código no me genera nada, me llega el correo en blanco.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo hice así:

```
select  'izq' as [td/@class], columna as td, ''
    , columna2 as td
from tabla
for xml path('tr')
```

Datos de tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE tabla (
 columna varchar(15),
 columna2 varchar(15)
);

insert into tabla values ('dato1','dato1.2');
insert into tabla values ('dato2','dato2.2');
```

Salida:

```
<tr><td class="izq">dato1</td><td>dato1.2</td></tr><tr><td class="izq">dato2</td><td>dato2.2</td></tr>
```

Puedes probarlo acá:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/514e5/2

Fijate que cambié raw por path.

Espero te sirva al menos como ejemplo, saludos!

Comment: Pues claro que funcionó, gracias! Y por qué la diferencia entre PATH y RAW? Pues no entiendo mucho al respecto, al menos el significado de esa parte del código. Saludos.

Comment: Es un poco complicado explicar todo pero lo más básico es que (según la documentación): raw transforma cada fila del resultado de una consulta en un elemento xml que tiene un identificador genérico row si no se le indica otro, por su parte path proporciona una manera de mezclar elementos y atributos (de allí que se pueda colocar el atributo class), además de proporcionar formas de anidar los elementos para poder representar estructuras más complejas.

Comment: Te dejo la documentación: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-ES/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017